# Sql group by browser like

Tags: php, sql

Hi I got in my database logs about users browser, and it shows, f.ex:
Firefox 6.0.2, Firefox 6.0.0 
Chrome 14.0.835.163 and other versions....
and more

it's all about version of browser. my question is it possible to do sql question where browser name is -> firefox (all versions), chrome(all version). And i need count them
Now I got something like this:

```
SELECT `logs`.`log_browser`, COUNT(*) AS `amount` 
FROM `logs` GROUP BY `log_browser`
```

But it returns me Firefox 6.0.2 and Firefox 6.0.0 as different row 
Is it possible? Or do I must do it in php with result?

Comment: Is perfomance an issue here ? Solutions are great but takes a lot process time. If so try njk solution without LOCATE and a specific number like 5 then match results with full names from PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this? This uses `LOCATE` to find the first space, and will group by and return the left part of the browser name.

```
SELECT LEFT(log_browser, LOCATE(' ', log_browser)) AS browser, COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM logs
GROUP BY LEFT(log_browser, LOCATE(' ', log_browser))
```

### [See it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7548f/1)

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE logs (
  log_browser varchar(25));

INSERT INTO logs VALUES
('Firefox 6.0.2'),
('Firefox 6.0.0'),
('Chrome 14.0.835.163')
```

**Result**

```
|  BROWSER | AMOUNT |
---------------------
|  Chrome  |      1 |
| Firefox  |      2 |
```

Comment: This might not work if there is data like `Internet Explorer 6.0`

Comment: to speed up query you may use LEFT(log_browser, LOCATE(' ', 5) then take care at php stage

Comment: @ErdinçÇorbacı Can you expand on your comment? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: To get result faster LOCATE may not be used a number like 5 would work. For instance for Firefox 'Firef' will be returned. And then from php these result can be mapped to corresponding browser names.

Comment: @ErdinçÇorbacı Ah I see. You could also create a look up table and `JOIN` to that instead of doing it on the PHP side.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c85db/2)

```
select REPLACE(log_browser, substring_index(log_browser,' ',-1),'') log_browser, 
count(*) cnt
from logs group by log_browser;
```

Comment: What about the other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

If execution speed is not a problem, previously given (by someone else - but deleted) answer's extended version would be useful. You can add any other browser name and group different syntaxes with OR

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN `log_browser` like '%Firefox%' Then 'FIREFOX'
WHEN `log_browser` like '%Chrome%%' Then 'CHROME'
WHEN `log_browser` like '%Explorer%' Then 'INTERNET EXPLORER'
WHEN `log_browser` like '%Opera%%' Then 'OPERA'
ELSE LEFT(log_browser,10) 
END Browser, count(*) from logs
group by 
CASE 
WHEN `log_browser` like '%Firefox%' Then 'FIREFOX'
WHEN `log_browser` like '%Chrome%%' Then 'CHROME'
WHEN `log_browser` like '%Explorer%' Then 'INTERNET EXPLORER'
WHEN `log_browser` like '%Opera%%' Then 'OPERA'
ELSE LEFT(log_browser,10) 
END
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use the substring function in the group by clause, assuming the browser identifies themselves in at most n characters, eg chrome is 6 letter you could do:

```
SELECT `logs`.`log_browser`, COUNT(*) AS `amount` 
FROM `logs` GROUP BY SUBSTRING(`log_browser`,1,6)
```